# Moment.js not parsing javascript date correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm getting a date from SQL Server which then passes through ASP.NET. I'm iterating through a list of objects in jQuery and want to display some dates along with other data. However, no matter what time is coming from the database (a variety of date/times from earlier), the minutes always read 10. What's going on?

Here's some web browser console output. These were all entered at different minutes past the hour, but they all say 10 past.

```
this.CreatedTime = /Date(1507924194433)/
moment-formatted = 10/13/17 12:10pm
this.CreatedTime = /Date(1507924096347)/
moment-formatted = 10/13/17 12:10pm
this.CreatedTime = /Date(1507923917443)/
moment-formatted = 10/13/17 12:10pm
this.CreatedTime = /Date(1507923693083)/
moment-formatted = 10/13/17 12:10pm
this.CreatedTime = /Date(1507667688047)/
moment-formatted = 10/10/17 1:10pm
this.CreatedTime = /Date(1507667348210)/
moment-formatted = 10/10/17 1:10pm
```

Here is the code:

```
$.each(data, function () {
   console.log("this.CreatedTime = " + this.CreatedTime);
   console.log("moment-formatted = " + moment(this.CreatedTime).format("MM/DD/YY h:MMa"));
});
```

Here are the actual dates from SQL Server:

```
2017-10-13 12:49:54.433
2017-10-13 12:48:16.347
2017-10-13 12:45:17.443
2017-10-13 12:41:33.083
2017-10-10 13:54:04.227
2017-10-10 13:34:48.047
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the format to

```
MM/DD/YY h:mma
           ^^
```

`MM` is for months, `mm` is for minutes.

Comment: So you're saying it was doing exactly what I told it to do? Ha! That worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: `So you're saying it was doing exactly what I told it to do?` Yes, and this is what we should always assume as developers. Especially when we are working with well-tested libraries like `Moment.js`

Comment: Good point. I thought maybe I needed to indicate the input format, like this: moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");, but wasn't sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `10` being returned is the month. in moment `MM` is month. You want to use `mm`.

Answer (score 1):

your date format is incorrect, try `moment(this.CreatedTime).format("MM/DD/YY h:mma")`